# Cabal to setup a new Haskell project?

Tags: haskell, setup-project, scaffolding, cabal

Is it possible to (ab)use Cabal to have it create a generic Haskell project with a simple command, similar to what you can do in the Scala world with Sbt or Maven?

e.g.

```
> cabal create AwesomeProject
> ls
AwesomeProject.hs     awesomeProject.cabal     LICENSE     README     Setup.hs
```

or is there another tool for that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `cabal init --interactive` to have an interactive session with cabal. I've pasted the first few questions when using the command:

```
arash@arash-ThinkPad-SL510:~/test$ cabal init
Package name [default "test"]? 
Package version [default "0.1"]? 
Please choose a license:
   1) GPL
   2) GPL-2
   3) GPL-3
   4) LGPL
   5) LGPL-2.1
   6) LGPL-3
 * 7) BSD3
   8) BSD4
   9) MIT
  10) PublicDomain
  11) AllRightsReserved
  12) OtherLicense
  13) Other (specify)
Your choice [default "BSD3"]? 
Author name? MyName 
Maintainer email?
```

Hope this helps.